# Excel VBA: Find range of cells for each day (non specified) and apply formula in a new cell

Tags: excel, datetime, select, excel-formula, vba

this is my first time posting but a quick thank you to the community for all the help this site has already gave me at University & Work.

**Problem Summary:**
I have network data, recorded every 15 minutes by day in a datetime format, with the bit rate in and out in separate columns.
The goal is to apply several formulas to each *day* (such as In Average, Out 90th Percentile etc.)
However, these formulas need to be applied to every single day, without a specific day being inputted by the user or included in the code.

This is where I am really struggling, I've spent a couple of days now trying to crack it but every similar example I can find requires a user specified date.

The reason I need VBA for this task, is because I have over 50 reports each with a month's data, eventually the code will import each report, apply the formulas then export them as CSVs for use in another workbook.

**Current Spreadsheet Example**

```
Time             | In Bit Rate | Out Bit Rate
01/02/2017 15:00 | 11200       | 42300
01/02/2017 15:15 | 14100       | 47400
01/02/2017 15:30 | 11300       | 42300
02/02/2017 15:00 | 12100       | 44100
02/02/2017 15:15 | 11500       | 42600
02/02/2017 15:30 | 12400       | 44700
```

**Desired Outcome Example**

```
Time             | In Bit Rate | Out Bit Rate | In Bit Rate Average | Out Bit Rate Average
01/02/2017 15:00 | 11200       | 42300        | 12200               | 44000
01/02/2017 15:15 | 14100       | 47400        |                     |
01/02/2017 15:30 | 11300       | 42300        |                     |
02/02/2017 15:00 | 12100       | 44100        | 12000               | 43800
02/02/2017 15:15 | 11500       | 42600        |                     |
02/02/2017 15:30 | 12400       | 44700        |                     |
```

Essentially the main difficulty I'm having is making the date selection, and ensuring the code runs for each and every day, I assume a loop would be useful in this instance but I'm not sure how it would pick out each separate day to begin with.

The one idea I started to pursue was to extract the date from each date time value into a new column, then handle the new date cells as 'duplicates', then I would have my row selection. However, this didn't feel like perhaps the most effective way of completing the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Data is supposed to be in sheet "MyData". The present code just perform operations with column 2 ("In Bit Rate"). You'll have to adjust it to fit your needs. Basically, data is temporary stored in an array. This code would work only if column A is ordered. Anyway, I think the main interest to you lies in the [Day](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b4h8sxy(v=vs.90).aspx) function.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

    lLastRow = Worksheets("MyData").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ReDim MyArray(1 To 1) As Variant

    For i = 1 To lLastRow
        If (Day(Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i + 1, 1)) <> Day(Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 1))) Then
            MyArray(UBound(MyArray)) = Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 2).Value
            Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(MyArray)
            Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(MyArray)
            Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(MyArray, 0.9)
            ReDim MyArray(1 To 1) As Variant 'reset array for next day
        Else
            MyArray(UBound(MyArray)) = Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 2).Value 'add data to array
            ReDim Preserve MyArray(1 To UBound(MyArray) + 1) As Variant 'now array is 1 element longer

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: After a bit of adjustment your code seems to work as intended! Thank you very much. I'm unfamiliar with arrays in VBA so I will have to investigate further, but the functions you have outlined have been extremely useful, so thank you again.

Comment: Glad to help! Mark as accepted if it fit your needs please... And a array is only a bunch of things. You can access elements like `MyArray(0)`, `MyArray(1) ` and so... In your case, I'd set two arrays: `MyInBitArray` and `MyOuBitArray`.

Comment: Sorry to ask you a follow-up question, do you have any experience with the Day function not picking up all dates? Your code works well when I run it directly in the file, but when I call the macro in another macro (to run it on multiple reports) it starts missing all dates up to the 12th of each month. I am assuming it could be a British/American date mismatch issue but am unsure.

Comment: Not really, but I'm far from being an expert. 1) The first thing I would try is to check if your time cells are properly format as date. For example, in an empty column write the formula `=A1+1/24` (if time is in column A), and drag down. This should add one hour to your data. 2) The second try would be do add a reference to the workbook: instead of `Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 4)` set an explicit reference: `Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\myworkbook.xls")` and then replace with `wbk .Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 4)`

Comment: What do you mean by "I run it directly in the file"? You are calling the sub from another Workbook?

Comment: In case anyone reads this thread, the solution to a date based array being misread in a csv file is to declare the dates to be interpreted locally. This I assume is because in csv the code defaults to the American date format. Example code `Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myFolder & myFile, Format:=xlDelimited, Local:=True)`

Answer (score 0):

A formula solution.
Assuming your columns are `A, B, C, D and E`, type the following formula in `D2` then copy/paste it along all the cells in of `D and E`.

```
=IF(DAY($A2)<>IFERROR(DAY($A1), 0),AVERAGEIFS(B:B,$A:$A,">="&INT($A2),$A:$A,"<"&1+INT($A2)), "")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will give it a shot. If it works I will consider how I can input the formula using VBA (it's a requirement unfortunately) so I have an additional method to that outlined by CMArg just in case.

Comment: You're welcome, it's good to have more than one solution, the one of @CMArg is good as well.